# Accessing a Linked server

Tags: sql-server-2012, linked-server, odbc

I am fairly new to the whole DBA scene. With that said, i was able to get an ODBC connection established within Microsoft SQL Server 2012 to be able to access a database for a library. Now what I am trying to do is create queries to be able to manipulate that said DB within Microsoft SQL Server but am having trouble finding ways to be able to do so. Can someone please help teach me how to call upon that Linked Server DB to be able to manipulate it as I see fit. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A linked server is referenced just like you would reference a database, with multi-part naming - `LinkedSvrName.DBName.SchemaName.ObjectName`.  There isn't really anything else to "accessing" a linked server.

There are some settings you will need to be cognizant of to ensure you can return data; `RPC` and `RPC Out` for instance.  Also you will want to use linked servers sparingly as performance will suffer.  This should get you well on your way to Googling the rest of what you need to know.  This topic is really too broad to be covered in this format.